# viewpager return wrong index using custom adapter

Tags: android, indexing, android-viewpager, fragment, adapter

I want to use 6 fragment(1,2,3,4,5,6) in viewpager using custom adapter.

also, I use android.support.v4.app.

but getItem() method return wrong index.

for example, show second Fragment when myApp first loaded.

and right swiping Repeatedly,

2 -> 3-> 4 -> 5-> 6-> 6

and left swiping Repeatedly,

6 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 1

and right swiping Repeatedly,

1 -> 3 -> 4-> 5-> 6-> 6

.... PLEASE HELP ME ... i don't know why.....

SourceCode is here.

- mainAcitivity.java

  ```
  //viewPager
  viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
  final MyViewPagerAdapter adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commitNow();

  viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  ```
- MyViewPagerAdapter

  ```
  public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

  public Fragment Fragment1;
  public Fragment Fragment2;
  public Fragment Fragment3;
  public Fragment Fragment4;
  public Fragment Fragment5;
  public Fragment Fragment6;
  String [] output = new String[5];

  public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);

      fm.executePendingTransactions();
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

      if(arg0==0){
          return new Fragment1();
      } else if(arg0==1){
          return new Fragment2();
      } else if(arg0==2){
          return new Fragment3();
      } else if(arg0==3){
          return new Fragment4();
      } else if(arg0==4){
          return new Fragment5();
      } else if(arg0==5){
          return new Fragment6();
      }

      return new Fragment1();
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      return 6;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
      return POSITION_NONE;
  }


  }
  ```
- Fragment1

  ```
  public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

  public Fragment1(){

  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment1, container, false);

  }

  public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
  }

  }
  ```
- Fragment2, 3, 4, 5, 6 is Same

Comment: Dont override getItemPosition method, also you should not keep any reference of your fragments in the class, it cause memory leaks

Comment: You should use FragmentStatePagerAdapter when you have a lot of Fragments to load, in this case it is better to inherit from FragmentPagerAdapter